# Number of telemetry topics bound to a Google IoT core device registry limited to 10?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I see that the number of telemetry topics that can be configured are limited to 10 . Is there a way to increase that if not any plan to increase this limit?

Comment: What's the use case that you're shooting for? Do you need to have different topics for it? Or could you manage splitting the telemetry handling in different ways? Perhaps embed all telemetry into one channel, but use Cloud Functions or Dataflow to split it out into different handlers? What is it you're actually doing with the telemetry data?

Answer (score 0):

So yes it seems even though they have pagination showing on the page, it is limited to 10 total:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas#project_device_and_telemetry_limits

This is absurd ... everyday I find a new reason that i'm upset I went with Google's IoT solution instead of one of the other competitors which is far superior in functionality ... ughhhhh